# Where / How is security information passed to SharePoint?

Tags: security

If I execute a query in SharePoint, my security information is passed along with the query.  I'm using Developer Tools in I.E.(F12) and am trying to see where this information is passed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you checked *FedAuth* cookie?

Comment: Use Fiddler instead of F12. https://www.telerik.com/fiddler